# "I love" versus "I've loved" usage

Tags: past-tense

Which quote is proper?

> "I believe in love at first sight because I've loved my mom since I opened my eyes."

or

> "I believe in love at first sight because I love my mom since I opened my eyes."

Answer (score 3):

The second form is grammatically wrong. "I've" is of course a contraction of "I have". The form "I have loved X since" is the correct present perfect verb tense, while "I loved X since" is simply incorrect.

Comment: I was in the middle of typing pretty much the same thing but you beat me to it so have my +1 instead.

Comment: I think you mean "I love X since"?

Comment: @jimm101 or that. It's wrong either way.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill yup ... just not sure if you want to edit the post to match the OP's question. :-)

Comment: But doesn't "I've loved" imply something that occurred in the past and does not continue to the present, so "I don't love her any more"? Grammatically it's correct, but I think "I love" is better in this specific case.

Comment: @laugh no, not at all. "I have loved her all my life" includes all of the past as well asl the present moment. "I love her" refers only to the present.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, "I've loved" is the more correct solution. When dealing with past tense, such as sharing stories about former/current relationships, you will use words such as have or had.

> I have loved you ever since I met you.

The example above shows a more formal version. Here is a more casual version:

> I've loved you ever since I met you.